# Como empacotar aplicação electron para windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

atualmente crie uma aplicação com o electron, da forma que fiz adicionei scripts javascript externos com scriptsrc para que funcione tanto no electron como em uma página web.

porém estou com problemas para gerar o executável para windows com o electron-packager

o problema é que aparentemente não está carregando algumas funções que quando com o comando npm start funcionam, o único comando que funciona é o botão sair.

estou carregando os scripts desta forma:

```
<!-- node_modules -->
  <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
  <script src="../main.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Vendor -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/vendor/framework7.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Core -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../core/f7.core.js"></script>
  <script src="../core/core.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../core/CommonTypes.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Controller -->
  <script src="../controller/Token/token.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

O Comando que estou mandando para gerar o executável é:

> electron-packager src UniPipe --platform=win32 --arch=all --version=1.6.2  --icon=assets/img/icon.ico --out=Release --electronVersion-string.CompanyName=OmegaInc --version-string.ProductName=UniPipe --version-string.ProductVersion=0.0.5

Queria saber se estou fazendo algo errado, se eu posso incluir os scripts dessa forma, pois da forma que funciona com npm start não funciona no executável.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?